# How to better handle database connection errors in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have asp.net mvc application, it uses linq to sql to connect to database.
How to stop handling all requests to application when there is many database connection erors?

There will be when database is down or there is wrong connection string. Will be good to stop application and show for all users simple message for all requests during some period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [app_offline](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx), if you want to close access to the website during maintenance work etc.

Comment: But how to do it automatically. For example if there is many erors catched, disable aplication for 2 min.

Comment: You need to code that yourself. There's no built in support for that.